# Auth.js (NextAuth v5) middleware issue with MongoDB

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I have a problem with the implementation of the middleware, I presume. In the beginning, I used Firestore with test rules. However, as I didn't know that the server shouldn't use the client SDKs, I tried to change it to admin SDKs and have even tried MongoDB. The problem is that I get the error below:

Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'stream' module.
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime
at  (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/globals.js:33)
at Object.get (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/globals.js:33:19)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js:617:45)
at (middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/src/middleware.js:1152:1)
at **webpack_require** (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
at fn (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js:9:27)
at (middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/src/middleware.js:1163:1)
at **webpack_require** (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
at fn (file:///Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:10:30) {
middleware: true
}

And when I restart the development I get a ginormous amount of errors, all of which have the exact same message except their dependency names:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'dependencyname' in '/Users/arman/Documents/Code/istut/istut-v2/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

By the way, the code inside my credential login's authorize function is causing this. This is happening due to some kind of leakage of the auth.config or auth.ts files to the middleware, I assume.
I refactored my code such that it uses MongoDB, and the app doesn't have a single problem except when I add even the most simple console.log((await usersCol()).find()); inside the authorize function.

I would be more than willing to provide more information regarding the related files if need be.

Heaps of  thanks ahead of time :)

Comment: Found the workaround below:
https://blog.stackademic.com/authentication-and-authorization-on-the-edge-with-auth-js-nextauth-5-and-mongodb-5903d7e95f99